# PHP e MySQL: Banco de dados não atualiza

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Boa tarde a todos, eu estou fazendo uma tela para edição de informações pessoais.
O meu código para capturar os dados digitados é este:

```
<?php
require("../config/functions.php");
require("../classes/BDConnection.class.php");
require("../classes/Academico.class.php");
session_start();

$connection = new BDConnection();
$connection->Connect();
$con = $connection->getConnection();

$login = $_SESSION['usuario'];
$password = $_SESSION['senha'];

$email = ClearString($_POST['Email'], $con);

//VERIFICAR SE O NOVO EMAIL JÁ EXISTE NO SISTEMA, EXCETO O DO PRÓPRIO USUÁRIO QUE ESTÁ ALTERANDO
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM academico WHERE email='".$email."' AND (login <> '".$login."' AND senha <>'".$password."');");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1){
    echo "<script>alert('ERRO: E-mail já cadastrado no sistema. Por favor, tente novamente com outro endereço.');
    window.history.back();</script>";
    die();  
}

$user = new Academico();

//INFORMAÇÕES PESSOAIS
$user->setNome(ClearString($_POST['NomeCompleto'], $con));
$user->setDataNascimento( ClearString($_POST['DataNascimento'], $con));
$user->setTelefone( (!empty($_POST['TelFixo'])) ? ClearString($_POST['TelFixo'], $con) : null);
$user->setCelular(ClearString($_POST['TelCelular'], $con));

$user->setEmail($email);

$user->setCidade(ClearString($_POST['CidadeNatal'], $con));
$user->setEndereco(ClearString($_POST['Endereco'], $con));
$user->setBairro(ClearString($_POST['Bairro'], $con));  

$user->setComentario( !empty($_POST['ComentarioAdicional']) ? ClearString($_POST['ComentarioAdicional'], $con) : null);

if($user->AtualizarDados($con)){
    echo "<script>alert('Seus dados foram atualizados');</script>";
}else{
    die('<h3>Erro ao atualizar dados.</h3><br />'.mysqli_error($con));  
}

?>
```

Os dados estão sendo capturados normalmente, eu testei todas as variáveis com *echo*, porém quando chamo o método *AtualizarDados()*, é retornada a mensagem de sucesso, entretanto os dados não estão sendo atualizados no BD.

método AtualizarDados():

```
function AtualizarDados($con){
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE academico SET nome='".$this->nome."', email='".$this->email."', data_nascimento='".$this->dataNascimento."', endereco='".$this->dataNascimento."', cidade='".$this->cidade."', telefone='".$this->telefone."', celular='".$this->celular."', comentario='".$this->comentario."', bairro='".$this->comentario."' WHERE login='".$this->login."' AND senha='".$this->senha."';")  or die('ERRO: '.mysqli_error($con));

        if(!mysqli_error($con)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: É totalmente não recomendado receber os valores do POST diretamente na *query* sql. Você precisa tratar as entradas antes. Para isso existe o PDO ou no caso MySQLi. Dê uma olhada no *link* a seguir:
[Evitando SQL Inject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Uma maneira fácil de se trabalhar com o banco de dados é utilizar uma biblioteca chamada RedBeans: [http://www.redbeanphp.com/](http://www.redbeanphp.com/) Dê uma olhada na página oficial. Tem exemplos super fáceis de como utilizar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe duas situações, se você quer saber se executou o comando ou se o comando afetou registros. No caso pra saber se ele alterou algum registro é com o `affected_rows`.

```
if($mysqli->affected_rows > 0){
    return true; // registros alterados
}else{
    return false; // não alterado
}
```

Comment: executei esse código, e está retornando false. Será problema é no BD ou a sintaxe SQL?

Comment: @RaphaelHenrique Da um `echo` na query que você está montando: `echo "UPDATE academico SET nome='".$this->nome."', email='".$this->email."', data_nascimento='".$this->dataNascimento."', endereco='".$this->dataNascimento."', cidade='".$this->cidade."', telefone='".$this->telefone."', celular='".$this->celular."', comentario='".$this->comentario."', bairro='".$this->comentario."' WHERE login='".$this->login."' AND senha='".$this->senha."';"`

Comment: Verifica o que está aparecendo e executa a mesma query direto no banco de dados pra ver o resultado.

Comment: Os valores de login e senha estavam sendo passados como vazio, eu tinha esquecido de setar o objeto com esses atributos... Muito obrigado pela ajuda, sua dica me mostrou o erro. resolvido!

Answer (score 1):

```
function AtualizarDados($con){
$sql = "UPDATE academico SET nome='".$this->nome."', email='".$this->email."', data_nascimento='".$this->dataNascimento."', endereco='".$this->endereco."', cidade='".$this->cidade."', telefone='".$this->telefone."', celular='".$this->celular."', comentario='".$this->comentario."', bairro='".$this->comentario."' WHERE login='".$this->login."' AND senha='".$this->senha."'";

   if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
       echo "Atualização feita com sucesso!";
   } else {
       echo "Error ao atualizar: " . $con->error;
   }
}
```

Tenta fazer isso. (CORRIGIDO)

Comment: continua com o mesmo problema, dá a mensagem de sucesso, mas quando eu verifico os dados no BD, eles não mudaram

Comment: Acho que achei!

data_nascimento='".$this->dataNascimento."', endereco='".$this->dataNascimento."' <<< Os valores estão repetidos

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!